# Docker: Could not connect to any X display

Tags: docker

Although the container should have the needed privileges to connect to the display, I got this error each time:

```
docker exec -it my_container

/# rqt

QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1
Could not connect to any X display.
```

The following command has been used to run the container:

```
sudo docker run -itd --restart unless-stopped --name my_container --privileged --net=host --gpus all \
    --env="NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all" \
    --env="DISPLAY=$DISPLAY" \
    --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
    --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
    my_image:v1.1
```

Comment: I was running into issues with docker and ssh in the mix. This URL seems promising https://blog.yadutaf.fr/2017/09/10/running-a-graphical-app-in-a-docker-container-on-a-remote-server/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to run the following command in your terminal:

```
xhost +local:docker
```

Then try again, it should work:

```
docker exec -it my_container

/# rqt
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've been running around trying every solution under the sun for a QT xcb error and this is the only thing that was effective.